# Alignment issue when input field file name is big, how to solve the issue ...?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, input, textfield

**in `input type="file"`, when file name is big(more words),then alignment is not proper...**

[image]

I want.., when the file name will be big, then It will show like

> From -**New_InkDrops_HD_Green_screen_Template(1080p)fhdighdghfdgd9sfghfdughifdgh9dfgh9fdhjfd9ughdfsfjdsighifdsu h8uhrd8gthreughreuig 8hru8treht8urehtg9erhter87htgerugt.mp4**

> To -
> **New_InkDrops_HD_Green_screen_Template . . .**

in this short type,

**how to do that...?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS rule on that input element:

```
input {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The effect you're after is called "text-overflow".
Details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow